# Convert a HTMLelement to a string in JS

Tags: javascript, html, browser, console

I have an HTMLElement, that looks like this:
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOhSw.png)

I want to convert it into the same text I will get if I was to select the text in the browser and copy it,

I tried using this:

`newDivText.innerText`

but it would output: `@KSZ`

and when I select and copy the element manually, it would output: `@KSZ :maam:`

how do I get the same string I would get as I would manually select and copy it on the browser

Comment: I guess that's discord and you should include that in the question.

Comment: no thats an html website

Comment: So I guess that this website is intercepting the copy comment to insert different thing into your clipboard. Without knowing what is it its impossible to guess

Comment: So maybe I can fake copy it into a string or something? without actually copying @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.